# How do I remove a trailing comma on an array list on Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I hope you had a great day today. I have some difficulties implementing commas into my code so that the list of numbers is displayed nicely. Here is my code. Any suggestions and advice are appreciated.

```
from random import randint
def randomIntegers(): 
    numbers = []
    for i in range(10):
        numbers.append(randint(1, 100)) #Range of random numbers goes up to 100.
    print(f"The numbers are: {numbers}")

    print("The elements of the list at an even index are: ", end=' ')
    for i in range(10):
        if i % 2 == 0: 
            print(numbers[i], end=' ')

    print("\nThe even elements in the list are: ", end=' ')
    for i in range(10):
        if numbers[i] % 2 == 0: 
            print(numbers[i], end=' ') 

    print("\nAll the elements in reverse order are: ", end=' ')
    for i in range(9, -1, -1): 
        print(numbers[i], end=' ')  

    print(f"\nThe first element is {numbers[0]} and last element is {numbers[-1]}.")
randomIntegers()
```

I would like to have my output of random numbers be like this **"All the elements in reverse order are 16, 67, 31, 46, 12, 7, 70, 92, 98, 67"** instead of having the comma at the end.

Comment: `print("All the elements in reverse order are: " + ', '.join(reversed(numbers)))`

Answer (score 0):

As flakes commented, the `str.join()` method joins the iterable passed to it by the string `str`. For example, `'-'.join([1,2,3,4,5])` returns the string `'1-2-3-4-5'`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler version of your code using list comprehension and joins. When testing, I found that joins on int lists needed to be cast to strings when joining. For some reason its not implied in the interpreter, but alas.

```
from random import randint
def randomIntegers(): 
    numbers = [randint(1, 100) for i in range(10)]
    print(f"The numbers are: {numbers}")

    print("The elements of the list at an even index are: " + ", ".join([str(numbers[i]) for i in range(10) if i % 2 == 0]))

    print("The even elements in the list are: " + ", ".join([str(n) for n in numbers if n % 2 == 0]))

    print("All the elements in reverse order are: " + ", ".join([str(n) for n in reversed(numbers)]))

    print(f"The first element is {numbers[0]} and last element is {numbers[-1]}.")
randomIntegers()
```